# Can I say dim range $T = $ dim null $S$ + range $S$ if $S \in \mathcal{L}(V,W)$, and $T \in \mathcal{L}(U,V)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Can I say dim range $T = $ dim null $S$ + range $S$ if $S \in \mathcal{L}(V,W)$, and $T \in \mathcal{L}(U,V)$?

The reason I asked this is because I am doing Q22 of section 3.B on *Linear Algebra Done Right*.

> Suppose $U$ and $V$ are finite-dimensional vector spaces and  $S \in \mathcal{L}(V,W)$, and $T \in \mathcal{L}(U,V)$. Prove that $$\text{dim null }ST \leq \text{dim null }S + \text{dim null }T$$

My failed trail is as follow:

dim range $T = $ dim null $S$ + dim range $S$ (from S)

dim $U$ = dim null $T$ + dim range $T$ (from T)

dim $U$ = dim null $ST$ + dim range $ST$ (from $ST \in \mathcal{L}(U,W)$)

then

dim null $T$ + dim range $T$ = dim null $ST$ + dim range $ST$

dim null $T$ + dim null $S$ + dim range $S$ = dim null $ST$ + dim range $ST$

dim null $ST$ = dim null $T$ + dim null $S$ + dim range $S$ - dim range $ST$

**The trial seems not working. Maybe range $T = $ dim null $S$ + dim range $S$ is wrong in the first place.**

Comment: Your first step is wrong indeed. There is nothing which says that $T$ should depend on $S$. Moreover, your notation is a bit weird in that statement. You say the range (a set) of $T$ is a number plus another set. You can define adding numbers to sets but I am not sure what your thought was?

Comment: If ai were you I would more argue in the trend: given a 'vector' in the nullspace of $ST$, show that you can relate this to a vector in the nullspace of $S$ or $T$

Comment: @StanTendijck The notation was a typo. My thought was since $ST(u)$ can be written as $S(T(u))$, I thought the range of $T$ is the domain of $S$.

Comment: If $T=0$, then $\dim \,\text{Ran}\, T=0$.

Comment: @John ok so what you need for it to work is that the range of $T$ is a subset of the domain of $S$. Per definition this is true since $T$s domain is part of $V$ which is exactly the domain of $S$ per definition.